# Renaming files on the remote network drive

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a couple of remote windows servers to which I have a very slow connection.

It is always a pain to copy a file there. But renaming files works much faster. Is it because  a transfer protocol recognizes a "rename" command and can do rename operation in-place, without actually deleting and re-coping the whole file again?

Comment: I have read this question about 5 times now and I can't for the life of me figure out what you're asking. Just about any FTP program will allow you to rename the file on the remote system so long as you have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 3):

To rename a file the operating system merely updates the directory entry on the disk. No data gets moved or copied.